# DecimalFormat precision not working correctly

Tags: java, kotlin, decimalformat

I would like to format a float using to a given precision using DecimalFormat. What I have is this

```
val formatter = DecimalFormat(if (precision > 0) "#0.${"0".repeat(precision)}" else "#")
```

Lets say the precision is 2 and when I do

```
formatter.format(20.0f).toFloat()
```

I get the output as `20.0f` and not `20.00f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting the `String` back to `Float`, thereby losing the format the `String` was in.

Instead, just print the output of `format`:

```
println(formatter.format(20.0f))
```

If you want the extra 'f', put it in your pattern:

```
val pattern = if (precision > 0) {
    "#0.${"0".repeat(precision)}f"
} else {
    "#f"
}
```